# Why parent class variable is hide if subclass having variable with same name?? why not avoided

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes as follows:

```
class parent
{
public:
    int a;
};

class child: public parent
{
public:
    int a;
};
```

When this inheritance has happened, the child class hides variable `a` from the parent class, but the parent class can still access `a` using scope resolution operator as `parent::a`. Why can't `parent::a` be avoided?

Can somebody please let me know why C++ does not allow `parent::a` to be "avoided" when hidden. I think keeping `parent::a` in the child class is waste of memory.

Comment: there is a reason people usually use meaningful name

Comment: If `child` does not need `parent::a`, then `child` is not a `parent`. Consider not using inheritance

Comment: What you are saying makes sense for the functions, which is known as function overriding, but not for variables.

Comment: Another option: Don't have a second `a` declared in `child`. Inherit `a` from `parent`.

Comment: If child has to use parent's "a" always, then, I think, C++ could have restricted us from defining new variable with same name

Comment: @pendyalasyam See Bo Persson's answer

Answer (score 3):

It is a general rule that you can declare the same name in an inner scope, and that hides any same-name items from any other scopes.

No special exceptions for classes.